# Reboot shortcut

Tags: linux, reboot, cgi

I need to haved a shortcut on my desktop to a URL which reboots my debian server and then says "reboot successfull" in the browser, if that was the case.

I do not want a putty reboot shortcut or something, I've thought about CGI but what do you recommend?

Comment: whats your mean about browser?

Comment: like a webserver or something which sends a command to the debian machine

Answer (score 1):

I needed this function once - along lots of other things and decided to do it with
http://www.webmin.com/

If you really want to be just a click away and have any doubts on security issues (i would have them) you can also create custom commands for custom users. e.g. an anonymous with the privilege to run just the init 6.

sounds a bit overdone for your problem but worked fine for me.

regards